# How to divide string in column separated by space to 3 new column in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, character

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below (in my real DataFrame I have of course many more columns):

```
COL1                                                | ...  | COLn
----------------------------------------------------|------|---------
ABC_20201105 XX_6M_BEFORE_100_150 PE_T1_20201105    | ...  | ...
ZZZ_20201105 XX_6M_BEFORE_200_400 PE_P1_20201105    | ...  | ...
ZBVA_20201105 XX_6M_BEFORE_100_150 PE_Z2_20201105   | ...  | ...
...                                                 | ...  | ...
```

And I need to divide values from COL1 to 3 new columns. Each part of value in COL1 is separated by space " ".

So, as a result I need somethin like below:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | ... | COLn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC_20201105 XX_6M_BEFORE_100_150 PE_T1_20201105 | ABC_20201105 | XX_6M_BEFORE_100_150 | PE_T1_20201105 | ... | ... |
| ZZZ_20201105 XX_6M_BEFORE_200_400 PE_P1_20201105 | ZZZ_20201105 | XX_6M_BEFORE_200_400 | PE_P1_20201105 | ... | ... |
| ZBVA_20201105 XX_6M_BEFORE_100_150 PE_Z2_20201105 | ZBVA_20201105 | XX_6M_BEFORE_100_150 | PE_Z2_20201105 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

How can I do this in Python Pandas ? in output i need to have also rest of my column from input DataFrame (as was presented in needed output) :)

Comment: use regex or split

Comment: How can I use regex or split ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a b c']})
a['col1']=a['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.split())
a[['col2','col3','col4']]=pd.DataFrame(a.col1.tolist())
a
```

If you have to do it for a lot of columns you can just create some column name list and use that in stead of adding them manually.
If you

Comment: Where can i implement mentioned list of columns ? Could you show example Luis? :)

Comment: If your col1 structure produces lists of the same length once you split, then you should be fine just by adding the names manually. I don't know how different the rest might look like as you only provided that example. I am not sure what you want to use it for, but I'd take a look at pandas explode function, it might be handier to structure the data that way.